# Swift - dictionary item to label

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to assign the value of Dictionary item to label. This Dictionary is inside an array.

when I print this item like so:

```
print(wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]);
```

it returns

```
Optional(410056)
```

which is the correct value. But I don't know why the Optional() is there.

Anyways when I try to assign this value to a label like so:

```
self.LData1.text = wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]
```

my code goes black and I get this error, only when I run it.

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how do I assign this to a label?

Comment: It seems `wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]` is an `Int?`, and you cannot assign an integer to a text string.

Comment: Dictionary accesses always returns optionals. Why? Because you'll get `nil` if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.  And in order to be able to return `nil`, it has to return a value that is of an optional type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]` is an optional `Int`. You can force unwrap it by appending `!`:

```
let someInt = wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]!
```

Then you could put it in a string like so:

```
LData1.text = "\(someInt)"
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
LData1.text = "\(wsQAshowTagArray![0]["LData1"]!)"
```

Note that this code will crash because you're force-unwrapping using `!`. You should really use `if let` or `guard let` instead. Optionals are a fundamental part of the Swift language. You should read [the docs on them](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) (they're short).

Comment: On a side note, instance and local variables should begin with a lowercase letter, so you should rename `LData1` to `lData1` (or maybe something more descriptive).